# Finding a Taylor Expansion for the following:

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

I have:

$$\frac{1}{1-z}$$ for $z_0=i$.

I have no idea how to do the Taylor Series expansion of this, around $z_0=i$, and then show it summation form.

I have:

$\frac{1}{1-z} = \frac{1}{1-i}+\frac{(z-i)}{(1-i)^2} + \frac{2\cdot (z-i)^2}{2!(1-i)^3}+\frac{6(z-i)^3}{3!(1-i)^4}\cdots$.... Is this a good start?

Thanks!

EDIT:

For this who care, I kind of got it figured out.

The $j^{th}$ derivative is:

$$\frac{d^j}{dz^j}\frac{1}{1-z}=\frac{j!}{(1-z)^{j+1}}$$, so, in summation form, our Taylor series:

$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{j!}{(1-i)^{j+1}}\cdot \frac{(z-i)^j}{j!}= \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(z-i)^j}{(1-i)^{j+1}}$$

Comment: There's a simpler way if you know that there exists only one taylor series around a given point. Do you know this?

Comment: I don't actually! I was just following the algorithm that my teacher gave me.... Mind sharing?

Comment: See [this](http://www.math.ucsb.edu/~helena/teaching/math122b/taylor_series.pdf) and note that $$\dfrac{1}{1-z}=\dfrac{1}{1-i-(z-i)}=\dfrac{1}{1-i}\dfrac{1}{1-\frac{z-i}{1-i}}=\dfrac{1}{1-i}\sum \limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(\left(\dfrac{1}{1-i}\right)^n(z-i)^n\right),$$ for all $z$ such that $\left|\dfrac{z-i}{1-i}\right|<1$.

Comment: That's slick! I'll have to send that to my memory banks for later use!! It's hard remembering tricks like this.

Comment: You'll be using it often, no need to make an extra effort to remember it. Most of this kind of problems are solved like this, it's a standard technique.